# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException merging dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

in my project there is a problem when I wanna add google play dependency to ues google map in my app. the problem is when I wanna run project I give these errors:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

and this is my dependencies:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile ('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46')
    compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0')
    compile ('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6')
    compile ('com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0')
}
```

I also remove all libraries cause I though they may had problem with google play 8.1.0 but nothings changed. also I tried to exclude `com.google.android.gms:play-services`  from all compile but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, pay attention to your **dependencies block**.
You are using different version of the same library and may be unnecessary  dependencies.

**Use the same versions** in any case.

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'   ARE YOU SURE?
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'  TWICE ? REMOVE IT
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'    APPCOMPAT contains it. REMOVE IT.
}
```

If the issue persists, you have too many methods. There can only be **65536 methods for dex**.

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Since the gradle plugin 0.14.0 and the Build Tools 21.1.0 you can use the [**multidex support**](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html).

Just add these lines in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Also in your `Manifest` add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you are using a own `Application` class, change the parent class from `Application` to `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: I tried  multiDexEnabled true before but it cause my app crashesh and wont solve the problem. :(

Comment: The multidex should resolve your build issue. If you are able to build and the app crashes you have another issue. Edit the question with the stacktrace or open another question if the problem is completely different.

Comment: without multiDexEnabled and new dependency my apps works right. i realy don't know why

Comment: Ok, I've just updated the answer. You don't have the issue any more, because removing the unnecessary libraries, you have less than 65536 methods in your apk. So you don't need the multdex.

Comment: I up your vote cause it very useful but my problem solved by adding:  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87' not just googleplay. but I have a more question about supports. I wanna use actionbar and MatterialDesign and my app can run on older version so what realy I need to add?!

Comment: The question resolved your question and your topic, of course it couldn't resolve all your need (how to know about the com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87?). For materialDesign, just add the appcompat and the design library.

Answer (score 1):

check your code .. 
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'**
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'**
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile ('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46')
compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0')
compile ('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6')
compile ('com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0')
```

}

with non-zero exit value 2 error happens when you have implemented any libraries twice in your code .. **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'**  and  **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'** 
please remove one of them.

also check other libraries in your 'libs' folder. this works for me. hope this will help you .

Comment: Also , If you have to keep libraries and methods, then you can enable multi dex support by declaring it in the gradle config.

defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}